# Disabling File Encoding in Reports

Tags: force.com

Iam looking to disable File encoding option while exproting reports in salesforce

How to disable that.?

Comment: I'm not certain I understand what you're asking. All files have to be encoded in some manner in order for them to be interpreted by the program that's going to read them. What encoding are you trying to disable?

Comment: I am trying to disable file encoding option while exporting.I want to disable the option to choose file encoding option.I want to give one default file encoding option.. I dont require to have all File Encoding option.?

Comment: As in UTF-8 or something else? Some of these are set as defaults in a user's profile.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those UI elements that are outside an administrator's ability to customize. I would suggest that you [post an idea on the IdeaExchange](http://ideas.salesforce.com/).